# Missing template articles/favorite in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add the Favorite function in my rails app. I added a partial favorite to `show.html.erb`, it will show the favorite link or unfavorite link, if I favorite a article, doesn't need to refresh whole page:

```
#app/views/articles/show.html.erb
  <div class="panel-body"><p><%= markdown(@article.content) %></p></div>
  <div class="panel-footer" id="favorite">
  <div><%= render 'favorite_link' %></div>
...
```

`_favorite_link.html.erb`:

```
<% if not Favorite.where(user_id: current_user.id, article_id: @article.id).first %>
  <%= link_to 'favorite', favorite_article_path(@article), {id: @article.id, method: :post}, remote: true %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'unfavorite', unfavorite_article_path(@article), method: :delete, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

`favorite.js.erb`:

```
$("#favorite").html("<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'favorite_link' %>");
```

`ArticlesController`:

```
def favorite
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.favorites.create(user_id: current_user.id)
  render 'favorite'
end

def unfavorite
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  favorite = Favorite.where(user_id: current_user.id, article_id: @article.id).first
  favorite.destroy
  render 'favorite'
end
```

When I click `favorite link`, it doesn't work, error info as below:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template articles/favorite, application/favorite with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/liuxingqi/Public/Sparta/my_blog/mongo_project/app/views"
  * "/Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:90:in `favorite'
```

but `unfavorite` works well. Hope someone can help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause, because the wrong parameters order, the `remote: true` doesn't work.

```
<%= link_to 'favorite', favorite_article_path(@article), {id: @article.id, method: :post}, remote: true %>
```

should be:

```
<%= link_to 'favorite', favorite_article_path(@article), {id: @article.id, method: :post, remote: true} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It search for a view with HTML extention no JS and what you have is favorite.js.erb, to fix that the request to favorite should be ajax request and with format: js  something like

```
articles_favorite_path(format: :js)
```

Comment: `<%= link_to favorite_article_path(@article, format: "js")...`, but doesn't work, The JQuery code shows in new page. `$("#favorite").html("  <a data-remote=\"true\" rel=\"nofollow\" data-method=\"delete\" href=\"/articles/55dc4ffb57d2fa0a9c000021/unfavorite\">\n    <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark\">unfavorite<\/span>\n<\/a>\n<!-- <div id=\"favorite\">\n\n<\/div> -->");`